# XAML convert a list to a list of controls

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik

I am using UI for UWP from telerik to draw a chart.
https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP

I am trying to data bind annotations and have them dynamically displayed.

I have bound one annotations like this:

View

```
<chart:RadCartesianChart x:Name="OhlcChart" PaletteName="DefaultLightSelected" Grid.Row="1">
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <chart:LinearAxis/>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <chart:DateTimeCategoricalAxis LabelFormat="{}{0,0:dd/MM}"/>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.Annotations>
                <chart:CartesianCustomLineAnnotation
                            HorizontalFrom="{x:Bind ViewModel.Annotations[0].Date1}"
                            VerticalFrom="{x:Bind ViewModel.Annotations[0].Value1}"
                            HorizontalTo="{x:Bind ViewModel.Annotations[0].Date2}"
                            VerticalTo="{x:Bind ViewModel.Annotations[0].Value2}"
                            />

                    </chart:RadCartesianChart.Annotations>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.Annotations>
</chart:RadCartesianChart>
```

View Model

```
public class ChartViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public class DataItem 
    {
         public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
         public double Value1 { get; set; }
         public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
         public double Value2 { get; set; }
    }
    public DataItem [] Annotations { get; }
}
```

How can I bind an enumerable amount of annotations like this:

```
public class ChartViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public class DataItem 
    {
         public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
         public double Value1 { get; set; }
         public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
         public double Value2 { get; set; }
    }
    public DataItem [] Annotations { get; }
}
```

`RadCartesianChart.Annotations` does not have an ItemTemplate property like ListView and GridView.

I want to bind my viewmodel such that there is a `CartesianCustomLineAnnotation` for each item in my view model array.

Comment: You are using ValueTuples. Valuetuples do not expose thier values as properties but as fields. Binding to fields is not supported by the Bindingsystem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However I am trying to bind a list to my annotations. I've updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem like this

```cs
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Angle[] Angles
    {
        get => _angles;
        set => SetProperty(ref _angles, value);
    }

    public class Angle
    {
        public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
        public double Value1 { get; set; }
        public double Value2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

code behind

```cs
public class ChartPage : Page
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty AnnotationsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnnotationsProperty",
            typeof(Angle[]),
            typeof(ChartPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(Array.Empty<Angle>(), OnAnnotationsChanged));

    public static void OnAnnotationsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var chart = (RadCartesianChart)d;
        var angles = e.NewValue as Angle[];
        chart.Annotations.Clear();
        if (angles == null || angles.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        angles
            .Select(x => new CartesianCustomLineAnnotation
            {
                HorizontalFrom = x.Date1,
                HorizontalTo = x.Date2,
                VerticalFrom = x.Value1,
                VerticalTo = x.Value2
            })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(chart.Annotations.Add);
    }

    public ChartPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.OhlcChart.SetBinding(AnnotationsProperty, new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ChartViewModel.Angles)),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this is the correct approach and doesn't memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

From this [document](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/annotations/annotations-provider), it shows we can use `RadCartesianChart.AnnotationsProvider` to achieve binding. But it can only use in WPF instead of UWP. So if you want to data bind annotations, it seems that you can only add the CartesianCustomLineAnnotation manually in xaml or code-behind.

**Update:**

If the ViewModel implements INotifyProperty, you can do Binding manually in code-behind. It will be a little complicated. I use **VerticalFrom** for an example.

```
ChartViewModel.DataItem item1 = new ChartViewModel.DataItem();
item1.Value1 = 10;

CartesianCustomLineAnnotation c1 = new CartesianCustomLineAnnotation();
c1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
c1.StrokeThickness = 2;

Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = item1;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value1");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(c1, CartesianCustomLineAnnotation.VerticalFromProperty, myBinding);

OhlcChart.Annotations.Add(c1);
```

Comment: Is there any way using attached properties, behaviours, etc to achieve model binding properly?

Comment: If the ViewModel implements `INotifyProperty` how would you do this in code behind to make sure it is handled properly?